# Display jQuery dialog before posting form to action method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a basic form. When the user submits a form, I'd like a jQuery dialog to display that asks the user if they're sure they want to continue.

Here's what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Continue": function () {
                    // continue and post data to action method
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    // close dialog and do nothing
                }
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Members", FormMethod.Get))
{
    Name: @Html.TextBox("searchName")
    <input value="Submit" type="submit" />
}
```

But I don't know how to hook the dialog into the form submission. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could do like:

```
$('form#yourFormId').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
});
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
           "Continue": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                $("form#yourFormId").submit();
           },
           "Cancel": function () {
           // close dialog and do nothing
          }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could do it by adding a click handler to the submit button that prevents the form submit but opens the dialog. Then submit the form within the `Continue` button callback

```
<-- adding ID to button-->
<input id="mySubmitButton" value="Submit" type="submit" />
```

JS

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Continue": function () {
                // am not familiar with parsing dotNet form helper, assume "Members" is form ID
               $('form#Members').submit()/* or use AJAX*/

            },
            "Cancel": function () {
               $(this).dialog('close')
            }
        }
    });

$('#mySubmitButton').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
   $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if i have a submit button, but i want to do some client side scripting before the form is posted i do this in the html:

```
<input id="mySubmitButton" value="Submit" type="submit" onclick="return MyFunction();"/>
```

in the JS i do this:

```
function MyFunction()
{//any code you wanted to run here
   return true;
}
```

You would need to alter MyFunction to prompt the user and to return false if they cancelled out of the action.

This method of calling a javascript function with a boolean return value is handy, particularly when you need to perform input validation prior to a post.

Comment: returning `true` will just let the form submit. Need to return `false`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close your dialog box and avoid the page to submit data, you need to put:

```
return false;
```

Use redirect in your continue function of dialog box. You don't need to have a function and it will always works. I used this method for my asp.net website in a dialog box like you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Continue": function () {
                // continue and post data to action method
                // Redirect to a page 
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                // close dialog and do nothing
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}); 
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Members", FormMethod.Get))
{
    Name: @Html.TextBox("searchName")
    <input value="Submit" type="submit" />
}
```